# What will happen when a node is almost out of resource, when deploying K8s daemonset?

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

When deploying Kubernetes Daemonset, what will happen when single node (out of a few nodes) is almost out of resource, and a pod can't be created, and when there are no pods that can be evicted? Though Kubernetes can be horizontally scaled, I believe it is meaningless to scale horizontally as Daemonset would need every pod on each node.

Answer (score 1):

> Though Kubernetes can be horizontally scaled, I believe it is meaningless to scale horizontally as Daemonset would need every pod on each node.

[DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) is a workload type that is mostly for *operations workload* e.g. transporting logs from the node or similar "system services". It is rarely a good fit for workload that is serving your users, but it can be.

> what will happen when single node (out of a few nodes) is almost out of resource, and a pod can't be created, and when there are no pods that can be evicted?

As I described above, workload deployed with `DaemonSet` is typically *operations workload* that has e.g. an infrastructure role in your cluster. Since this may be more critical pods (or less, depending on what you want), I would use a higher *Quality of Service* for these pods, so that other pods is evicted when there are few resources on the node.

See [Configure Quality of Service for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/) for how to configure your Pods to be in a Quality of Service class, one of:

- Guaranteed
- Burstable
- Best Effort

You might also consider to use [Pod Priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/)

The question was about `DaemonSet` but as a final note: Workload that serves requests from your users, typically is deployed as `Deployment` and for those, it is very easy to do horizontal scaling using [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).